# Finished with Non Zero Exit Value 3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run my project, but I keep getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.blume.android"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(path: ':endpoints-backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile project(path: ':cloud-backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
compile 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0'
compile project(':endpoints-backend')
}
```

All Help is appreciated.

Comment: You most likely have a duplicate dependency in one of your `compile project(`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just change

> "**compile** fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])"

to

> "**provided** fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])".

It resolved my problem

Comment: It helped me too. You should mark this answer as solution to make people know that it really helps.

Comment: In my case this is not working, if i change to "provided" it give me error in some execution of code used by this libs 'httpmime-4.0.1.jar' lib "apache-mime4j-0.6.jar", in ws call. Can any body help for this ?

Comment: Provided means the libs are needed for compilation of the project, but they won't be distributed with it. If your app actually needs the libs (like the apache-mime4j-0.6.jar in the previous comment) and the runtime environment doesn't "provide" it (hence the name), then you have to use compile.

Answer (score 57):

add this:

```
android {
    // Other stuffs
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

Comment: After following a lot of solutions , finally this solution helped me. I'll have to check out for drawbacks if any. Thanks.

Comment: I got this err:

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForGoogleDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3`

This answer helped me.

Comment: android {
    defaultConfig {}

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
    }

    buildTypes {
    } }

Comment: Any idea why there is nothing in logs regarding heap size? Although it helped.

Answer (score 6):

Increased the HEAP size to 2g or 4g. 
Filename: build.gradle

```
android {
        defaultConfig {}

        dexOptions {
              javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

        packagingOptions {
        }

        buildTypes {
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1.Go to your app build.gradle

2.include the following:
        dexOptions 
           {
              javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
                  }

Answer (score 1):

**1. Please check the Below Code For 
 1. When i am Using
    Firebase(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1) and GMS
    (compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
) then it gives me error**

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

**2. so i have added this line in gradle File**
`
defaultConfig 
 {
  multiDexEnabled true
}
and in dependacies

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
```

**3.so Code Working fine For Updated Version. and not working for Kitkat 4.4.2 device reason is Appcompact, Material Design not Working on that.So i have added below line code in gradle file**

```
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}
```

**4. And also have dome some changes with menifest file in**

```
 <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**5.Please Check the my Gradle file which working fine For Me you need to do changes .**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.projectName"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        //if 2g or 4g
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
    // important to run code on kitkat
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'

    // ImageLoader
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

    // Map
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'

    // Spinner
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'

    // Volley
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

    //CropImage
    compile project(':CropImage')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score -3):

I am just change

"compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])"

To

provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

Comment: Good day, copying existing old upvoted and accepted answers is not encouraged on Stack Overflow.