# Android Studio: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > Process finished with non-zero exit value 3 during the module bulding

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, shinobi, android-multidex

I'm trying to add Chart library called ShinobiCharts into my project using the following tutorial.

https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/using-shinobicharts-with-android-studio-1-0

Module is imported, but when i trying to add charts into the Gradle config i always get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

**App Gradle Config:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            // Enabling multidex support.
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.11'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    // UI TESTING DEPENDENCIES
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    //androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2'
    // ORM DATABASE DEPENDENCIES
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    // MULTIDEX SUPPORT
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile project(':shinobichartsandroidlibrary')
}
```

**Library module Gradle config:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add Multidex support into library but without the luck.

How can i sove it please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did you check [Finished with Non Zero Exit Value 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720831/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-3)?

Comment: @Sufian Where to apply conditions mentioned in Your Link? In App or Library Gradle config file?

Comment: I m not sure but make `minSdk` and `TargetSdk` same for both Library and app

Comment: use ./gradlew assemble --info to get the stacktrace

Comment: @redrom in the gradle file