# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' error in my project while I added new dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**I didn't added any libraries / jars in my project( in libs ) only this dependencies.**

My build.gradle file.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.example23"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
compile 'com.naver.android.helloyako:imagecropview:1.0.3'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
}
```

Once I am adding this  " compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0' " into my project I am getting this

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Error is coming while I run my project....

If I remove this " compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0' " dependency my program is working fine.

Sometimes if I added Facebook dependency also the same error is coming...

[image]

Comment: post your whole error

Comment: I added an Image with the ERROR what I am geting @Aashvi

Comment: Finally I got it with   
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html

Comment: Thanks to IntelliJ Amiya and Aashvi .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use below code also with **IntelliJ Amiya** answer.
In some case this code work for me

```
 dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
}
```

you can do by make an Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { .. }
```

or

```
override 
 attachBaseContext method and call MultiDex.install().
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
super.attachBaseContext(base);
MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Otherwise (if your application does not have custom Application implementation), declare MultiDexApplication as application implementation in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<application
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
.. >
..
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you for ur support @Aashvi I added  " multiDexEnabled true ", error is gone. Now I am getting new error with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout

Comment: @Ram23 I added some other way also which can help you in this error

Comment: Small suggestion in ur answer add a note somwthing like with "multiDexEnabled true" in build.gradle.

Comment: i didn't added because IntelliJ Amiya already added that answer . but i am updated now

Comment: S, @IntelliJ Amiya added .... Half answer in that post and half in ur post... so, that's y.... I told ...

Comment: Hi  @Aashvi  I am getting a new problem, when I added " compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6' " dependency I am getting " Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
 "  this error Please help me out  ( In libs folder nothing (jar) I added )

Comment: @A-n-v-e-s-h i am not familiar with this error. so i can't help you. but can suggest  this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720831/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-3/30930734#30930734

Answer (score 3):

At first you can use `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'` instead of yours . You can read my answer **[DexIndexOverflowException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top)**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
}
```

> http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: @Ram23 Did you add `multiDexEnabled` ? Then clean,Build & Sync your project

Comment: Just now I added " multiDexEnabled true ". now I am getting new exception with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat am checking this Thank you @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @Ram23 https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%3A+android.support.v7.appcompat&oq=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%3A+android.support.v7.appcompat&aqs=chrome..69i57.695j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'`

Comment: I added appcompat-v7 in my build.gradle. That's the first dependency.... in my project

Comment: yes yes .I checked .You used `v7:23.1.1'` i proposed `v7:23.0.0'`

Comment: I changed to 23.0.0, Now I got new  " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.GcmRegistrar$Singleton " error in parse .... :( :( ..

Comment: At the end I am getting one by one error with "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:" .... After added multiDexEnabled, So do U have any idea with this relation between these two...

Comment: this occurs when the intended class is not found in the Class Path.

Comment: @Ram23 Mine real pleasure .You can read my answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: HI @IntelliJ Amiya I am getting a new problem, when I added " compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6' " dependency I am getting " Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
 "  this error please help me out... ( In libs folder nothing (jar) I added )

Comment: please post this as a question

Comment: Ok, Thank you @IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 0):

add

```
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

in your gradle before the compileSdkversion...