# Could not find property 'compile' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@397740e0

Tags: java, android, gradle

I was working through a lecture using the `parse.com` starter program for two days with no issue. I went away for a few minutes and without anything that I can see being changed and now it won't sync. I have searched but found nothing that I can see wrong. Thanks in advance for your help.

This is the error:

```
Error:(36, 0) Could not find property 'compile' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@397740e0.
```

Open File

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { 
            url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' 
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {


    compile
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' compile
    'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0' compile
    'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0' compile
    'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}

/* Uncomment if you enable ProGuard and you want to automatically upload symbols on build.
parse {
  applicationId "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID"
  masterKey "YOUR_MASTER_KEY"

  // Make symbol upload automatic. Otherwise, use e.g. ../gradlew parseUploadSymbolsDebug;
  uploadSymbols true
}
*/
```

Comment: compile    'com.android.support:design:22.2.1' !  Y ur using same dependency twice !!!!

Comment: compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0' 
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0' If ur using these 2 dependencies U may get other error in future definitely  ... so, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864267/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-error-in-my-project-while-i-adde

Comment: Hi Anvesh  I have struggled with this issue before. This is how it comes in the Android starter project from Parse.com. I will research that further.

Comment: It occurred suddenly when I was adding a Preference Fragment from menu.

Comment: For me When creating new activity this issue happened.

Comment: For me too this happens automatically after creating fragment/activity..dont know why? but everytime this happens i have change it manually

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You've used compile as a property, but it isn't one. You need to pass a string argument to it.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' 
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0' 
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

**EDIT**:
As people have mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't have two identical dependencies. However this doesn't cause the problem you described. I believe it might cause an "Unexpected Top Level Exception" when you build with gradle.

Comment: Thanks too, this strange layout of the "compile" section occurred to me spontaneously : in a project where line breaks were properly placed, at some point somehow they got all messed up line in the OP's code. Weird. It occurred just after a Java JDK update, if that's any clue.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't notice that the build.gradle was modified by the `Android Studio` strangely.

Comment: Same issue - the problem was caused immediately after updating my Java JDK to 8r92 in the Project Structure dialog.

Comment: IMPORTANT: don't put a comma after each line :)

Comment: In my case, it's due to formatting issue.Whenever I tried to create new activity whole build.gradle file becomes messy.I don't know the reason.But studio throws same error every time.

Comment: Google is aware of the bug, but seems to think it has been fixed (in an unspecified pre-release version around July 2016); see [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37079036]. I just hit this bug in Android Studio 2.3.1 -- AS mangled my carefully documented (woefully, documented in-line only) dependencies for no reason when I created a FullscreenActivity through the new file wizard, and then presented me with a nonsensical error message.  Anyone else who has encountered this issue in a recent AS build, please ping the linked issue tracker so they know the bug is still live

Comment: @CCJ I have encountered with the same error, i have AS 2.3.2. When i create a new activity it is changing my whole `build.gradle`. I have checked with the link you have given but link seems broken.

Comment: Just rearrange by pressing `enter`at the end of each row: `compile 'a string here'↲`

Answer (score 11):

```
compile
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' compile
'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0' compile
'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0' compile
'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

Just format like this :

```
compile'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' 
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0' 
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0' 
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, and as @Akhil suggested you have to make sure the compile syntax is as above.

For me after an upgrade the gradle compile lines breaks were removed,

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

Comment: No idea why you are answering an already answered question from a year ago. But it is a problem some times when building that causes your gradle file to get be messed up (It still happens on the current version of Android studio / Gradle).