# Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I was about to add google map activity, and my android studio showed this error

> Error:Error:line (25)Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

```
 <a href="openFi`here`le:C:\Users\dhami\Desktop\uber1\ParseStarterProject\build.gradle"></a>
```

this is my parse project Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {                                                                              compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.parse.starter"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms``:play-services:9.2.1'
}
```

this is my project gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
}}allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}  } ext {
compileSdkVersion = 23
buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
minSdkVersion = 14
targetSdkVersion = 23   }
```

Comment: in dependencies section why there is **`** before opening brace? is that typing mistake or what?

Comment: try with java plugin, **apply plugin: 'java'** java plugin brings various tasks like 'compile', 'test', 'jar' etc. for more info please refer to [java_plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just Change your line breaks , it will solve your problem

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
}
```

break line after each dependencies.

See answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33991915/4985413

Comment: This worked thanks! the automatic addition from Assistant (firebase assistant) was messing up the dependencies section and many of them were on the same line

Answer (score 9):

I got this error when I used the automatic creation of `Activity` in Studio. Apparently, studio tried to add `ConstraintLayout` dependency to my `build.gradle` file and this messed up my `build.gradle` file.

If this is the case, just use your version control and see what's messed up and correct it.

Answer (score 2):

No commas between separate line items, it's not JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this, and its working for me.

```
dependencies {
    //dagger hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46.1'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.46.1"
}
```