# Gradle indentation issue in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Every time I create a new Activity in AS 2.3 it messes up the build.gradle indentation that results in errors like this.

*Error:Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.*

I have to redo the indentations every time. Any idea how to fix this permanently?

Comment: I'm having the same problem my solution was to just keep the default format that android studio produces and the next time when it auto-reformat build.gradle it stayed the same. I know it's not a solution, and I hope someone know a permanent solution to this annoying problem

Comment: and please post your build.gradle file here to see what's exactly your problem

Comment: @humazed it looks exactly like the sample in the answer by Egek92 . I use source tree to discard changes to gradle file to get back the indentations. It is extremely annoying to do it every time though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265432/could-not-get-unknown-property-compile-for-object-of-type-org-gradle-api-inter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the lines which contain curly braces like:

```
compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-4') {
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback.core.net'
}
```

In order to avoid the bug just put all the lines with curly braces above the "usual" (i.e. `compile 'something'`) lines like this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-4') {
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback.core.net'
}
compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-4') {
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback.core.net'
}

compile 'com.bolyartech.forge.android:forge-android:6.1.0'
compile 'com.bolyartech.scram_sasl:scram_sasl:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:v0.9.3'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
...
```

Comment: brilliant! Thanks :D

Comment: @wick.ed Which part of this answer is telling something different than my suggestion ( don't change the gradle structure.) ?

Comment: @Egek92 I can't understand your answer, so probably other users have the same problem too.

Comment: @Egek92 "In order to avoid the bug just put all the lines with curly braces above the "usual" (i.e. compile 'something') lines like this:" this part. It explains exactly what "don't change gradle structure" meant.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use compile as a property and don't change the gradle structure.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' compile

 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
```

Sometimes Gradle build messes up the code like above, it still happens. Probably related to Java JDK updates.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. 
I don't understand what you mean by "don't use compile as a property".  Also, I am not explicitly changing the gradle structures. Everytime I create a new activity it automatically happens :(

Comment: @wick.ed I meant you shouldn't change the default format like I mention in the example, This kind of things are happening and there is no possible solution so far, best thing is keeping jdk and your IDE updated. Good luck!