# Gradle file is edited on creating new Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

On creating a new Activity by

> right-click on `app` > New > Activity > Empty Activity

Activity is created, but gradle file is auto-edited giving the error:

> Error: Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

It happens same with Fragments. I'm using Android Studio 2.3.

How do I resolve this?

**Code Sample:**

```
// retrofit dependency
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

// charts
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
```

After creating `Activity`

```
compile
    'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'compile
    'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'compile
    'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
```

Comment: Could be the `bug` I guess!

Comment: Remove the comments inside dependencies.

I had same issues and removing the comments inside the dependencies solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

The solution, for now, is to remove the comments inside the dependencies.

Comment: yep this worked for me, I had a bunch of comments inside compile body and removing them seemed to fix the issue :\

Answer (score 0):

This question is asked a few times before. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984981/gradle-indentation-issue-in-android-studio-2-3/42985170#42985170) is the most recent one.

This is a bug possibly related to Java JDK and there is no possible solution, temporary solution is re-format your Gradle like this:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```