# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:27 in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a this two error in android studio. How to fix this error.

```
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:27.+
    <a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:D:/android project/My` `Projects/MyApplication2/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

**and**

```
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:D:/android project/My Projects/MyApplication2/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

**This is my dependencies code**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**How to fix this error**

Comment: Can you just try changing   `27.+` to  `25.1.0` in both support libraries ?.

Comment: Have you included `mavenCentral()` and `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` in project gradle?

Comment: Now, I have `Error:(31, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:D:\android project\My Projects\MyApplication2\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>` this error

Comment: Which is your studio version ? If it is 3.0 or greater then change compile to implementation. Also make sure File->settings->Build,execution,deployment->Gradle->offline work unchecked.

Comment: @sunilsunny, my studio version is 2.3.3

Comment: @sunilsunny, it is already unchecked.

Comment: @moni123 Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39265837/3111083 for the issue `Could not get unknown property 'compile'`

Comment: @varad `jcenter()` is a superset of `mavenCentral()`

Comment: @sunilsunny This is not for my one. pls can you help me

Comment: @moni123 Try remove `appcompat-v7` line. You don't need it with `design` dependency

Comment: @sunilsunny I removed but not working. `Error:(31, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:D:\android project\My Projects\MyApplication2\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>`  now i have this error

Comment: That error is happening because you have an extra blank space in between 2 dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

To use support libraries starting from version 26.0.0 you need to add Google's Maven repository to your project's build.gradle file.

1. Open the build.gradle file for your application.
2. Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the 
   "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

Example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

For Android Studio 3.0.0 and above:

```
allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```