# Could not get unknown property 'implementation' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I've searched through previous post and can't find the answer to my question here is my code from my build.gradle file.

Error: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'implementation' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.loganwiley.findmyphone"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        compileKotlin {
            kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
        }

        compileKotlin {
            kotlinOptions {
                suppressWarnings = true
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'+
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'+
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'+
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.4'+
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.4'+
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'+
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'+
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'+
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265432/could-not-get-unknown-property-compile-for-object-of-type-org-gradle-api-inter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265432/could-not-get-unknown-property-compile-for-object-of-type-org-gradle-api-inter)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all those weird plus signs (+) you have after many of your dependency declerations. So, for instance, instead of:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'+
```

Write:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```