# A problem occurred evaluating project app - Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, dart

I have a flutter app that I wish to use the Google Firebase Analytics. But, my build.gradle project is showing this error.

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'platform' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I had looking for answers, and I find these ones:
[Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265432/could-not-get-unknown-property-compile-for-object-of-type-org-gradle-api-inter)

and: [Could not find property 'compile' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@397740e0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991832/could-not-find-property-compile-on-org-gradle-api-internal-artifacts-dsl-depen/33991915#33991915)

But none of them solved my problem. This is my gradle archive:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.widget_um"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation platform 'com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Can please attach flutter doctor logs, src> build.gradle  and gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. For better understanding

Comment: show your build.gradle file

Comment: there is a build.gradle in the question, I will attach the other file.

Answer (score 0):

There's the gradle app level archive. (The question archive is the src level, and I have some problems to edit it)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.19041.572], locale pt-BR)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

• No issues found!