# ProcessException Error while executing

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried look for this error, but unluckily, no solution yet. So need to post here.

[image: error image]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pongodev.recipesapp"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 5
    versionName "3.0.3"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
// Main libraries, you always need this libraries in your project. do not remove them.
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

// Important library to create material design. do not remove this.
compile project(':materialDesign')

// Library to create tabbar
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'

// Library to create ripple effect. work together with materialDesign library.
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.2.2'

// Library to create rounded, circle, and any shape image.
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.4.0'

// Library load lazy images.
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'

// Library to create simple list.
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'

// Library to create complex clickable list.
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'

// Library to create material dialog.
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.1'

// Library to create animation imageview.
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code snippest you can use in **build.gradle**

**Change to**

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
```

**Instead of**

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
```

I hope it will help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Try to use this solution   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991832/could-not-find-property-compile-on-org-gradle-api-internal-artifacts-dsl-depen

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: We have to change and is still the same problem