# How to solve Could not find method compile() for arguments [file collection]

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I imported a project into Android Studio, but the project is not getting built.
the error message I get is:

```
Error:(20, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [file collection]  
on object of type 
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

<a href="openFile:C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\WSAppAndroid 
\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

As shown in image-1 posted below, in gradle.build (project) I have these libraries in the dependencies section.

I googled how to solve this issue and among the posts I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991832/could-not-find-property-) which tackles the same problem. But the accepted answer does not solve the problem i have.

As an attempt to solve this issue, can I use `compile`  instead of `compile files` 
in build.gradle? how it can be done?
my question is

**image-1**

[image]

**build.gradle (project)**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to  
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.7' // 1.8?
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}

dependencies {
compile files('gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
compile files('app/libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
compile files('app/libs/iDappsImagesLib_v0.2.jar')
compile files('app/libs/iDappsToolsLib_v0.1.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
}
```

compile-on-org-gradle-api-internal-artifacts-dsl-depen/33991915#33991915

Comment: where is the image ?

Comment: share your build.gradle

Comment: did you `apply plugin: 'java'`

Comment: @OussemaAroua please find the image and build.gradle(project) posted

Comment: @LazerBanana please find the image and build.gradle(project) posted

Comment: What are the files / folder under `C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\WSAppAndroid` ? Do you have another `build.gradle` ?

Comment: @ToYonos can you please have a look at this question

Comment: @ToYonos the folder under C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\WSAppAndroid  contains the project foldeers such as .idea, app and so on

Answer (score 1):

compile has been replaced by implementation in newer version of gradle, replace compile with implementation and compile group with implmenetation group in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your local jars as dependencies I would suggest.

Adding `apply plugin: 'java'`

Adding your folder as a repository

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
}
```

then add them to the dependencies.

```
dependencies {
   compile name: 'whatever'
}
```

another thing is why do you add the Gradle wrapper as a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

well the problem here is that in the project uses local libs , so you need to add `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` now gradle will import the `jars` located in `libs` folder.

so you will have

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
compile files('app/libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
compile files('app/libs/iDappsImagesLib_v0.2.jar')
compile files('app/libs/iDappsToolsLib_v0.1.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
}
```

Comment: i did as you suggested but i till get the same error

Comment: if it's a simple project building it from 0 will be your best choise