# Impossible to run app with Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, gradle

I have an issue with Parse. I had the sdk (downloaded on Parse.com and unzip inside /libs folder in my project) and when I build everything is good.

But when I run the app,I have this following error :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I don't know what to do, I search and tried everything I found on StackOverflow and github repo of Parse but nothing works :/

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Which devices did you try to run the app on?

Comment: I try with Nexus 5 with API 23 (Target to minimum sdk 4.4)

Comment: Link your build.gradle file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple in your gradle file add these ...

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true

}

 // add dexOptions
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}


dependencies {
provided fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
 // add multidex dependency 
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

reference: [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' error in my project while I added new dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864267/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-error-in-my-project-while-i-adde)

Comment: One more IMP thing, U have to add either ' parse jar ' file  or  " parse dependency ". If U added both again U will get an error.

Comment: Thanks ! With this it works like a charm :) I think it was the dexOptions who's missing ;)

Comment: Thank you, it works for me too, but I don't understand the whole issue.

Comment: I have found the explanation from this site http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: Yes, that was right. If ur developing ur app morethan the limit U have to use MultiDex

Answer (score 3):

Try to clean your project (Build -> Clean Project) or try to add this:

```
 defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true
 }
```

to your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code to your build.gradle (module: app)

```
dependencies{
...
...
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}
```

and no need of adding multiDex.

Hope this should work.