# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in 4.1 and working with 5.1.using multidex in android studio

Tags: android, parse-platform

I stuck in a very stupid type of problem since 3 days and still no luck.
I am using Parse.com for sign up and sign in. I am also using twitter and facebook.
My application class oncreate method:-

```
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, AppConstants.PARSE_APP_ID, AppConstants.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
}
}
```

My gradle build :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "rsi.com.componentsdemo"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    jumboMode = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}}dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
compile('org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v7'
}
compile project(':lib')
compile files('libs/Parse-1.11.0.jar')
```

}

I am using parse 1.11.0.jar lib in libs folder.

Now the thing is that same code is running in android 5.0.1 device but getting crash in 4.1.1 version.

LogCat is as follows:-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android
                                                                        at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:191)
                                                                        at rsi.com.componentsdemo.ComponentsDemoAppClass.onCreate(ComponentsDemoAppClass.java:20)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me to sort out this problem. Thanks!!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use a jar file for Parse and you don't declare the needed dependencies in the build gradle script? https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing

Comment: Can you debug it with a JellyBean device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `incremental = true` means multiple dex option is enable & things are not working for lower device like 4.1 (AFAIK it wont work below 4.4)
because of [multiple dex file](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.htm)

I face same issue with for below 4.4 devices.Issue is not with `ParsePlugin`.

To resolve issue what i give in my `build.gradle`

```
dexOptions {
        incremental true
        // here heap size give 4g i got this thing from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/P_TLBTyFWVY

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //    your dependencies which you are using.

}
```

Entire `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}
configurations {
//    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        /*
        releasebuild {
            keyAlias 'hellotest'
            keyPassword 'hellotest'
            storeFile file('path to keystore')
            storePassword 'hellotest'
        }
        */
    }
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    /* if you got error regarding duplicate file of  META-INF/LICENSE.txt from jar file
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    */
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        incremental true
        // here heap size give 4g i got this thing from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/P_TLBTyFWVY

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.myapp.packagenme"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releasebuild
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releasebuild
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //    your dependencies which you are using.

}
```

And in Application class i have extended [MultiDexApplication](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html)

for [MultiDex.install](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#testing)

```
    public class MyAppClass extends MultiDexApplication{
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        MultiDex.install(newBase);
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this.. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @DeepakSharma let me know if you got any issue

Comment: sure bro.. I will tell you after trying t he above code

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.. Its working .. you make my day.. +1 cheers.. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143065/impossible-to-run-app-with-parse/34148132#34148132