# Why does use of multiDexEnabled (true) allow the app to build but constantly crash?

Tags: android, git, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

An app I am working on (base code not written by me, containing a number of large libs which can't be removed). On a recent run it started responding with the message:

This only occurs when the app tries to build when using the run arrow, it successfully builds when calling "rebuild" or "clean".

A solution included on line is to use the multiDexEnabled true ([multiDex documentation here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/building/multidex.html).)

Using this I was able to get the building with both "run" arrow and "rebuild". However the app built and run on phone crashes withthe following error message:

```
12-11 16:17:16.963 28868-28868/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-11 16:17:17.023 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 10471 (common_google_play_services_updating_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.023 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0021
12-11 16:17:17.023 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x28e8 at 0x2e in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability;.zza
12-11 16:17:17.033 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 10465 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.033 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0012
12-11 16:17:17.033 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 10462 (common_google_play_services_notification_ticker) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.033 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0013
12-11 16:17:17.033 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 10437 (common_ic_googleplayservices) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$drawable;
12-11 16:17:17.033 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0039
12-11 16:17:17.033 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 10462 (common_google_play_services_notification_ticker) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.033 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0099
12-11 16:17:17.043 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzj
12-11 16:17:17.043 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 616: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
12-11 16:17:17.043 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
12-11 16:17:17.043 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x28c4 at 0x6c in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.zza
12-11 16:17:17.043 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x28e9 at 0x6e in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.zza
12-11 16:17:17.083 28868-28907/com.myname.myappcoop I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
12-11 16:17:17.083 28868-28907/com.myname.myappcoop E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
12-11 16:17:17.083 28868-28907/com.myname.myappcoop E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
12-11 16:17:17.113 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 358K, 3% free 16887K/17276K, paused 11ms, total 12ms
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 8714 (static_string) in Lcom/myname/display/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x000b
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 8710 (static_string2) in Lcom/myname/display/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x000e
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 8711 (static_string3) in Lcom/myname/display/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0011
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 8716 (static_string4) in Lcom/myname/display/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0014
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 8717 (static_string5) in Lcom/myname/display/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0017
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 8721 (static_string6) in Lcom/myname/display/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x001a
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 8720 (static_string7) in Lcom/myname/display/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x001d
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 8719 (static_string8) in Lcom/myname/display/R$string;
12-11 16:17:17.133 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0020
12-11 16:17:17.143 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/MAIN: Context 1 : com.myname.myapp.Application@4268dfe8
12-11 16:17:17.163 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.myname.myapp.view.FalseActionBar$1', referenced from method com.myname.myapp.view.FalseActionBar.initializeView
12-11 16:17:17.163 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3015 (Lcom/myname/myapp/view/FalseActionBar$1;) in Lcom/myname/myapp/view/FalseActionBar;
12-11 16:17:17.163 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x002a
12-11 16:17:17.163 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 10366 ($SwitchMap$com$myname$myapp$view$FalseActionBar$TitleMode) in Lcom/myname/myapp/view/FalseActionBar$3;
12-11 16:17:17.163 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0005
12-11 16:17:17.163 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5db9 at 0x2c in Lcom/myname/myapp/view/FalseActionBar;.initializeView
12-11 16:17:17.163 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5dba at 0x46 in Lcom/myname/myapp/view/FalseActionBar;.initializeView
12-11 16:17:17.163 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-11 16:17:17.163 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4162fba8)
12-11 16:17:17.163 28868-28868/com.myname.myappcoop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                           Process: com.myname.myappcoop, PID: 28868
                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myname.myappcoop/com.myname.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.myname.myapp.view.FalseActionBar
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.myname.myapp.view.FalseActionBar
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
                               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
                               at com.myname.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:96)
                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
                               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929) 
                               at com.myname.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:96) 
                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myname.myapp.view.FalseActionBar$1
                               at com.myname.myapp.view.FalseActionBar.initializeView(FalseActionBar.java:61)
                               at com.myname.myapp.view.FalseActionBar.<init>(FalseActionBar.java:46)
                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
                               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929) 
                               at com.myname.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:96) 
                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
12-11 16:17:46.173 28868-28868/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28868 SIG: 9
```

The where the code is crashing (Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myname.myapp.view.FalseActionBar$1) is when a listener is being declared. It was originally in another class extending on click listener so I brought it into the code, but that did not help.

```
    title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (mode) {
                case NONE:
                    //Nothing!
                    break;

                case BACK:
                    if(delegate != null){
                        delegate.goBack(backLocation);
                    }
                    break;

                case HOME:
                    if(delegate != null){
                        delegate.goHome();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I originally thought the issue was with the inflater though now I am fairly sure it must be with the use of multiDex.

What is multiDex doing that is causing the crash on inflation?

Comment: If you really want to ensure you're back in the previous state, besides running `git reset --hard`, don't forget to run `git clean -fxd` as it will delete every files not tracked by git

Comment: @gturri - thanks, after reverting fully I was able to get to work. This helped me understand where the problem is coming from. I am getting an error when trying to run the app where java.exe is exiting with exit code 2. This is fixed when I use multiDexEnabled, but this appears to be the cause of the app crashing.

Comment: I have updated the question to give context to error message in light of new information

Comment: post your gradle file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to do following things

1. in build.gradle add

   ```
   dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
   }
   ```
2. enable multidex

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ```
3. Create a file extends with MultiDexApplication as following

   ```
   public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

       @Override
       protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
           super.attachBaseContext(base);
           MultiDex.install(this);
       } 
   }
   ```

   and make this 'App' class as application class in manifest as below -

   ```
   <application
       android:name=".activity.App"
   ```

Comment: Thank you So Much.
i resolve my Issue after 2 days.
Your Answer Work for My Case

Answer (score 4):

Just add

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `application` XM tag as property.

This will solve all your problems.

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` comes because of your project not getting file at run time. so try this suggestion and let me know is it solved or not.

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' error in my project while I added new dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864267/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-error-in-my-project-while-i-adde/33864437#33864437)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are using android studio.
Try to add this line too to the gradle file and retest the same

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```